# Connect to Oracle 10g

Tags: vb.net, oracle, date, oracle10g

I finished my project with MSSQL 2008r2 database And vb.net

My company have oracel ERP System  (oracle10g+ora6i form)

And I need to move same data from my project. To the company's system
I use 
System.Data.SqlClient
library

i need way to connect my Project to erp db

Comment: Oracle and Sql Server use different dialects of SQL. Many things are the same, but many things are also different. Date functions and datatypes, for example, are completely different between the two systems. You need to be prepared to sit down and **review every single query and column**, to adapt from one to the other.

Comment: Also, both Oracle 10g and Sql Server 2008 R2 are completely **END OF LIFE**. This means they no longer get any updates... _not even critical security patches_. It's dangerous and irresponsible to continue using them, and upgrading to a supported platform should be job #1.

Comment: The `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace is the .NET Data Provider for **SQL Server**. You cannot use it to connect to an Oracle Database.

Comment: Wait a minute. Your company uses Oracle 10g and Forms 6i (both older than majority of users on StackOverflow, I presume) but OK, that's what they have, there's nothing much you can do about it. How come you developed an application which uses completely different database and development tool? If you wanted to "migrate" both database **and** application to Oracle, I guess you'd rather start over, but this time using Oracle. There are utilities that can help with the *database* part, but I don't know of any capable of migrating a .NET application to (ancient) Oracle Forms 6i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the connection string

```
string oracle_conn= "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = server_Ip_oracle)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = database_name)));User ID=User/Schema;Password=password;Unicode=True";
```

and then use the code like

```
    using (OracleConnection objConn = new OracleConnection(oracle_conn))
{
Your code here 
}
```

Comment: i use vb.net not c#

Comment: @MohamedAllam Then it's `Dim oracle_conn As String = ` etc. and `Using objConn As OracleConnection = new OracleConnection(oracle_conn)` `'your code here` `End Using`.

Comment: I also suggest using `Configurations`

Comment: @Osamazx  
The Code Not work   do u have anther way

Comment: I didn't understand how to use it
Is it possible to write the full code?

Comment: Check this link , it's documentation mentioning the step one by one
https://developer.oracle.com/dotnet/vs2010-oracle-dev.html